# refreshing the data in a list and store, sencha touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, touch

I have an itemTapHold event on my list. In this event I make an ajax request like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({

        url: //goes to delete php script,
        method: 'post',
        params:

        {

        userid: userid,
        name: name

        },

        success: function (response) {


            Ext.Msg.alert( name + " is verwijderd");


        },

        failure: function (response) {



        }
});
```

This bit of code works, the tapped item will be deleted in my database.

The problem is how do i refresh my list/store? I already tried to refresh my list with `refresh()` which is actually working cause my checkboxes i have in my list will all go unchecked.

I also did a `console.log(Selections);`(which is the store my list is using) and it will return me the store with data before i deleted my record.

Am i missing something here?

PS. i also don't know where to put the refresh methods in my event? after, before or in my ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are are a couple of Store methods you can use:

1. remove( records )
2. removeAt( index )

In your success function you could call `store.remove(<your record>);`

Alternatively, you could get the index of the record with the userid then remove it.

```
var index = store.find('userid', userid);
store.removeAt(index);
```

The event fired by removing the record from the store will be caught by the grid and it should be updated accordingly.